# Polymer dom-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, null, polymer

While rendering with Polymer an array of objects, it keeps launching me an exception.

Here's the data model retrieved from server:

```
{
  "lastUpdate":"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmm",
  "info": [
    {
      "title": "Some nice title"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here's my Polymer component template:

```
<dom-module is="items-list">
    <template>
        <dl>
            <dt>last update:</dt>
            <dd>[[$response.lastUpdate]]</dd>
            <dt>total items:</dt>
            <dd>[[$response.info.length]]</dd>
        </dl>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{$response.info}}">
            {{index}}: {{item.title}}
        </template>
    </template>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

And here's the controller:

```
'use strict';
Polymer(
    {
        properties: {
            info: {
                type: Array
            },
            $response: {
                type: Object,
                observer: '_gotResponse'
            }
        },
        _gotResponse: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.info.length)
            {
                try
                {
                    //here I try to set info value
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            }
        },
        ready: function()
        {
            //set some default value for info
        },
        attached: function()
        {
            //here I request the service for the info
        }
    }
);
```

If tried to set info value as:

```
this.info = response.info;
this.set('info', response.info);
this.push('info', response.info[i]); //inside a loop
```

But the result breaks after rendering the first item, the exception launched is:
"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null**"

Answer (score 0):

If `info === $response.info` then why not just use `items={{info}}` in the repeat?

edit:
Try to modify your code in the following way.

```
'use strict';
Polymer({
    properties: {
        $response: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    _gotResponse: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
        ...
        this.$response = response
        ...
    },
    attached: function()
    {
        //here I request the service for the info
        someAjaxFn(someParam, res => this._gotResponse(res));
    }
});
```

You don't need an observer in this case.  You only use an explicit observer when the implicit ones don't/won't work.  I.e. `fullName:{type:String, observer:_getFirstLastName}`
or

```
value:{type:String, observer:_storeOldVar}
...
_storeOldVar(newValue, oldValue) {
  this.oldValue = oldValue;
}
```

if you are updating the entire array, ie `this.info`, then you simple use `this.info = whatever` once within your function.  If you don't want to update the entire array, just some element within it, then you will want to use polymer's native array mutation methods as JS array method doesn't trigger the observer.

Again, since your template doesn't use info, then you don't need the property `info`.  If you want to keep info, then don't store info within `$response`.  In fact, $ has special meaning in polymer so try not to name properties with it.  you can simply use the property `info` and `lastUpdate` for your polymer.

Last note, beware of variable scoping when you invoke functions from polymer.  Since functions within polymer instances often use `this` to refer to itself, it may cause 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' ..."** 
as `this` no longer refers to the polymer instance at the time of resolve.

For example, suppose your host html is

```
...
<items-list id='iList'></items-list>
<script>
  iList._gotResponse(json); // this will work.
  setTimeout(() => iList.gotResponse(json),0); //this will also work.
  function wrap (fn) {fn(json)}
  wrap (iList._gotResponse);  //TypeError: Cannot read property '$response' of undefined.
  function wrap2(that, fn) {fn.bind(that)(json)}
  wrap2 (iList,iList._gotResponse); // OK!
  wrap (p=>iList._gotResponse(p)) //OK too!!
  wrap (function (p) {iList._gotResponse(p)}) //OK, I think you got the idea.
</script>
```

Comment: Done, the issue still takes place